# Upload png via Batch corrupts image

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to upload a png file with a batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
echo user MYUSERNAME>> ftpcmd.dat
echo MYPASSWORD>> ftpcmd.dat
echo put C:\1234.png>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat my-ftp-server.com
del ftpcmd.dat
goto Ende
:Ende
pause
```

The upload works, but the png file is always corrupted.

What can I do?

Thanks and Greets
Thorsten

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default mode for `ftp put` is *ASCII* so the file will be terminated at the first x`1a` (^Z) character (an ancient EOF used since CP/M)

Before the `put` command, add an extra line

```
echo binary>> ftpcmd.dat
```

to switch to binary mode.

It may be easier to use

```
@ECHO OFF
(
echo user MYUSERNAME
echo MYPASSWORD
echo binary
echo put C:\1234.png
echo quit
)>ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat my-ftp-server.com
del ftpcmd.dat
pause
```

which will gather the output of the `echo`es within the parentheses and output them to a new file `ftpcmd.dat) (single`>` - create new file; double appends or creates)